# know the KRE version used in one app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to know how Scott shown the version of KRE used on the application that he launched:

[image: versions]

I know how show .NET version (System.Environment.Version) but this is the KRE version.

I've found this on his blog and I think he did that on events. This is his blog page where he did it: [scott blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETVNext.aspx)

Comment: Try to be clear in what you're asking.  Also, wth is a schoo't blog?

Comment: The question is clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics/RuntimeInfoMiddleware.cs#L66-L70) is how you get the runtime version programmatically.

If you just want to see it rather than using it in code, you might consider using the `RuntimeInfo` middleware from the `Diagnostics` package. See [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/samples/RuntimeInfoPageSample/Startup.cs) sample